# Fitch proof: Given $p(a), ∀x.(p(x)⇒p(f(x)))$, and $∀x.(p(f(f(x)))⇒p(g(x)))$, prove $∀x.p(x)$

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I know how prove: Given $p(a), ∀x.(p(x)⇒p(f(x)))$, and $∀x.(p(f(x))⇒p(g(x)))$, prove $∀x.p(x)$

But I have no idea how I can prove: Given $p(a), ∀x.(p(x)⇒p(f(x)))$, and $∀x.(p(f(f(x)))⇒p(g(x)))$, prove $∀x.p(x)$

I try:

Assumptions: $p(f([c]))⇒p(f(f([c]))$

Some operations: ...

And I have: $(p(f([c]))⇒p(f(f([c])))=>(p([c]) => p(g([c])))$

But how I can extract $(p([c]) => p(g([c])))$?

If I will have $p([c]) => p(g([c]))$, I can use induction to solve task

I don't need a complete solution, just a hint

Comment: What are $f$ and $g$?

Comment: f and g  are unary functions

Comment: For case `With P(x)→P(fx) and P(fx)→P(gx) you have P(x)→P(gx) ` it is easy, but what I need to do with 'With P(x)→P(f(x)) and P(f(f(x)))→P(g(x))'?

Comment: Is there a way to instantiate $x$ to $f(x)$? I believe that may be the way to tackle it - if not, what are the objects and functions available in your universe?

Comment: What are you referring to when you talk about induction and tree induction? I feel there must be some context missing here.

Comment: @MarkSaving is right. In the problem you want to solve and also in the one you say you know how to solve, the conclusion doesn't follow from the hypotheses. In both cases, a counterexample is given by a $2$-element universe $\{a,b\}$, with $p(a)$ true, $p(b)$ false, and both $f$ and $g$ being the identity function. Some additional assumptions are needed to make the inferences correct and to make sense of what you wrote about induction.

Comment: The Object universe consists of $a$ and the Function universe consists of $f, g$. These are the details that were left out.

In order to apply tree induction, the cases that need to be shown are:

1) $p(a)$ where $a$ is the only object in the object universe,

2) $\forall x.(p(x) => p(f(x)))$

3) $\forall x.(p(x) => p(g(x)))$

Applying induction from these 3 statements directly yields that $\forall x.(p(x))$

Comment: Before attempting to prove something "using fitch" or using any other logic, you should be able to prove it informally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're still thinking about this question, think of it this way:

The big hint is that when you perform Universal Elimination, how are you doing this? What is the placeholder you are using? Try to see if you can use the placeholder $f([c])$ instead of $[c]$ as usual and see what happens :)